# NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative gives wrong result when the precision is not MachinePrecision

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, arbitrary-precision, finite-difference-method

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1, fixed in 11.3 or earlier.**

---

I want to get a pseudospectral differentiation matrix by `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative ``.

```
nx = 8;  (* Grid size *)
x = N[Table[-Cos[(j \[Pi])/nx], {j, 0, nx}]];
(* -> {-1., -0.92388, -0.707107, -0.382683, 0., 0.382683, 0.707107, 0.92388, 1.} *)
```

The differentiation matrix is

```
dx = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, x, DifferenceOrder -> "Pseudospectral"]["DifferentiationMatrix"]
```

We can check that `dx.x` is 1.

```
dx.x
(* -> {1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.} *)
```

However, if we change the precision to 20 (arbitrary precision), the result is obviously wrong.

```
nx = 8;
x1 = N[Table[-Cos[(j \[Pi])/nx], {j, 0, nx}], 20]
dx1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, x1, DifferenceOrder -> "Pseudospectral"]["DifferentiationMatrix"]
```

`dx1.x1` is supposed to be 1, but it is far from 1.

```
dx1.x1
(* -> {22.50000000000000000, 2.649846074667681225, 0.535533905932737622, 1.323575230741387329, 0.500000000000000000, 2.451028024842430524, -6.535533905932737622, 125.57555066974850092, 252.50000000000000000} *)
```

Some elements of `dx1-dx` are far from zero (though most of its elements are close to zero).

Similar things happen for finite difference and periodic differentiation matrices. Is there a way to increase the precision and get the correct result?

Comment: The last column seems in error to me.  Yes?

Comment: Yes, only the last column of `dx1-dx` is far from zero.

Comment: I filed this as a bug. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Oh, actually I always found that `"DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"` seems not to work properly when a non-`MachinePrecision` `WorkingPrecision` is set, maybe this is the true reason?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The last column seems in error.  Here's a workaround for the sample problem, although it does not fix `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative ``:

```
dx2 = dx1;
dx2[[All, -1]] = -Reverse@dx1[[All, 1]]
(*
  {-0.50000000000000000000, 0.25989153247414500869, 
   -0.29289321881345247560, 0.36161567304292239214, 
   -0.50000000000000000000, 0.80995720221088751026, 
   -1.7071067811865475244, 6.5685355922720450889, 21.500000000000000000}
*)

dx2.x1
(*
 {1.00000000000000000, 1.000000000000000000, 1.000000000000000000, 
  1.000000000000000000, 1.000000000000000000, 1.000000000000000000, 
  1.000000000000000000, 1.000000000000000000, 1.00000000000000000}
*)
```

Hope that helps.

*Update 1*: Interestingly, this works:

```
NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, x1, x1, DifferenceOrder -> "Pseudospectral"]
(*  {1.00000000000000000,..., 1.00000000000000000}  *)
```

So does this:

```
dx1FN = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, x1, DifferenceOrder -> "Pseudospectral"]
dx1FN[x1]
```

*Update 2*: Here's another workaround to get the differentiation matrix:

```
Transpose[dx1FN /@ IdentityMatrix[Length@x1]]
```

*Update 3*: The `"DifferentiationMatrix"` is computed internally basically by calling

```
NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1, 0], {x1, x1}, 
  DifferenceOrder -> "Pseudospectral"][IdentityMatrix[Length@x1]]
```

This produces the erroneous matrix and should probably be considered a bug.
Strangely, it computes the $(0,1)$ derivative correctly.  So here is yet another workaround:

```
Transpose[
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[0, 1], {x1, x1}, 
   DifferenceOrder -> "Pseudospectral"][IdentityMatrix[Length@x1]]]
```